# SQL query to simulate distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM table t ORDER BY col1;
```

This gives me distinct combination of `col1` & `col2`.  Is there an alternative way of writing the Oracle SQL query to get the unique combination of `col1` & `col2` records with out using the keyword distinct?

Comment: Is it homework? It reminds me some school jobs I had to do :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the UNIQUE keyword which is a synonym for DISTINCT:

```
SELECT UNIQUE col1, col2 FROM table t ORDER BY col1;
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why you would want to but you could do

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_t GROUP BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1
```

Comment: sorry for the wrong comment. I want to avoid group by as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
select col1, col2
from table
group by col1, col2
order by col1
```

**or** a less elegant way:

```
select col1,col2 from table
UNION
select col1,col2 from table
order by col1;
```

or a even less elegant way:

```
select a.col1, a.col2
from (select col1, col2 from table
UNION
select NULL, NULL) a
where a.col1 is not null
order by a.col1
```

Comment: And, the 3rd answer should not have an `order by` inside the subquery at all.

Comment: The Union is clever because `UNION` has `DISTINCT` as default while `SELECT` has `ALL` as default operation.

Comment: @ypercube yep, but the group by seems to be the more elegant ^^

Answer (score 3):

Another - yet overly complex and somewhat useless - solution:

```
select *
from (
   select col1, 
          col2, 
          row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1, col2) as rn
   from the_table
)
where rn = 1
order by col1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `ORDER BY` be in the external query, too (or only there)?

Comment: thanks for the response this query executed real fast than all the other options.

Comment: @ypercube: you are right. It should be in the outer as well. It is needed in the inner as otherwise the row_number() does not really make sens - although it might actually work without. But as we all know: never rely on any order unless an `order by` is specified.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another ...

```
select
  col1,
  col2
from
  table t1
where
  not exists (select *
                from table t2
               where t2.col1  = t1.col1 and
                     t2.col2  = t1.col2 and
                     t2.rowid > t1.rowid)
order by
  col1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Variations on the `UNION` solution by @aF. :

**`INTERSECT`**

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableX
INTERSECT
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableX
ORDER BY col1;
```

**`MINUS`**

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableX
MINUS
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableX WHERE 0 = 1
ORDER BY col1;
```

**`MINUS`** (2nd version, it will return one row less than the other versions, if there is `(NULL, NULL)` group)

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tableX
MINUS
SELECT NULL, NULL FROM dual
ORDER BY col1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ...

```
select   col1,
         col2
from     (
         select col1,
                col2,
                rowid,
                min(rowid) over (partition by col1, col2) min_rowid
         from   table)
where    rowid = min_rowid
order by col1;
```